# Term for an increasing sequence of partitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I'm looking for the term for the following object, so I can economise on definitions. It feels natural enough but I can't find it anywhere.

The object is a sequence of increasing partitions. I.e. $\mathscr{P} \equiv \left(P_1, P_2, ..., P_L\right)$, where each $P_j$ partitions some set $X$ and where for any $x,y\in X$, $K \in P_j$, and $K' \in  P_{j+1}$, if
$x,y ∈ K$
and $x ∈ K'$
then $y ∈ K'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *refinement order* on set partitions of a set $X$ is the order such that $P \leq Q$ if and only if each part of $P$ is contained in a single part of $Q$ (and in this case one says that $P$ is a refinement of $Q$ or that $Q$ is a coarsening of $P$).  This turns the collection of set partitions into a lattice, often called $\Pi_n$ when $X = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ is finite, and it looks like you are asking for a chain in the lattice of set partitions of $X$.